# How to make top to bottom animation with react styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, styled-components, react-animations

I'm trying to recreate the slider on Gatsby's website but using the styled components library instead of the emotion library they used. The issue is the animation doesn't do anything and the list of strings I pass into the component get concatenated together.

[Gatsbyjs.org](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)

[Code for their slider component](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/www/src/components/slider.js)

**My slider.js:**

```
import React from "react"
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components"


const topToBottom = keyframes`
  0%: {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  6%: {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  10%: {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25%: {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  29%: {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80%: {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100%: {
    opacity: 0;
  }
`;

const SliderDiv = styled.div`
  display: inline;
  & span: {
    animation: ${topToBottom} 10s linear infinite 0s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;

    :nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: 2.5s;
    }

    :nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }

    :nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 7.5s;
    }
  }
`;

const Slider = ({ items, color }) => (
  <SliderDiv>
    {items.map(item => (
      <span key={item} css={{ color }}>
        {item}
      </span>
    ))}
  </SliderDiv>
)

export default Slider
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the backticks css accepts scss format? have you tried to change it to plain css?

Comment: I am not familiar enough with scss and css to know the difference. If you point out which parts I should change I can try and let you know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works as expected if you remove the `:` from the css code inside the Styled Component:

```
span {
// not
span : {
```

and

```
0% {
// not
0% : {
```

I've tested the code in a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j315l6om73)

```js
import React from "react";
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";

const topToBottom = keyframes`
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  6% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  29% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(30px);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
`;

const SliderDiv = styled.div`
  display: inline;
  & span {
    animation: ${topToBottom} 10s linear infinite 0s;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;

    :nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: 2.5s;
    }

    :nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 5s;
    }

    :nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 7.5s;
    }
  }
`;

const Slider = ({ items, color }) => (
  <SliderDiv>
    {items.map(item => (
      <span key={item} css={{ color }}>
        {item}
      </span>
    ))}
  </SliderDiv>
);

export default Slider;
```

I know I looked for this errors a couple of times :)

To make it more clear, in `styled-components` you write `css`, not `css-in-js`

Hope it helps!